# build Screen with LDFLAGS="-static"

Tags: linux, compilation, static, glibc, gnu-screen

I want to build [screen](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/screen/screen-4.2.1.tar.gz) static, so that I can use it as standalone binary on embed devices.

```
screen-4.2.1# ./configure LDFLAGS="-static" && make
```

I got this warning:

```
/screen.c:933: warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

the reason for this is answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766403/4454057).
So it is not possible to use "getpwnam" an some other functions out of glibc within a static linked binary, if i understand this right.

So my question is. Is there any way to build screen static (because I'm actually cant believe there isn't), and if not is there a good replacement which can be build static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to build screen static

Sure: just ignore the warning and voila, you have a fully-static `screen`.

Now, that fully-static screen will not work when moved to a system with different version of `GLIBC`, and so is useless for that purpose.

In general, contrary to popular belief, fully-static binaries are *less* portable than dynamic ones on UNIX systems. Your desire to build such fully-static binary is very likely misguided.

> if not is there a good replacement which can be build static?

You could try using alternate `libc` implementations, such `uClibc` or `dietlibc`, which may not place such a restriction on fully-static binaries.

Comment: I've had reasonable results so far with ignoring the warning - it has worked better than NOT compiling static for me.  When you say non-static is more portable - could you explain that a bit more? Is there more that needs to be done besides just compiling and copying the binary to the system you need it on?

Comment: @chrisputnam9 You can ask a separate question (it's free to ask).